# Changing projects SVN address in Eclipse Subversive

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, subversive

I just started using SVN, and I set up a repository, because everyone were saying that version control is important and having backup.

Now I had to make a first commit of my project, and I'm new to SVN, so it asked the URL and I gave it the url for my SVN+Project name, which is `http://lalala.com/<MyProjectName>`.

I thought this will be good, but then I discovered that my project was stored on the root folder in SVN, next to `trunk branches tags` etc.

But actually when I commit my project I want it to go directly to my `trunk` folder. So two questions...

1)How can I change the SVN address for my project in Eclipse Subversive?

2)How would I delete the folder that is on the root folder of SVN, should I just manually delete it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) If the special folders do not exist, use the SVN perspective to create them. Add your project root folder directly under trunk. Use Checkout As Project in the context menu in the SVN perspective. You may use Show Location Properties in the context menu to alter the URL.

2) Just delete the folder and commit

Good luck!